# Karma patterns do not match any files in Angular Project

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

**Problem**

I am trying to get a few tests working using Karma and Jasmine in a practice Angular project. When I use attempt to run the Karma tests using the `Karma start` command in the command line, a browser opens (Chrome, in this case), but does not display any tests. It displays only the Karma version, the debug button, and a message indicating Chrome is idle (see pictures below). In the command line, Karma gives the warning

`All files matched by "D:/Documents/CSCI_Project/test-app/*.js" were excluded or matched by prior matchers.`

It also gives multiple warnings of the form

`Pattern "D:/Documents/CSCI_Project/test/test-app/testPractice.spec.js" does not match any file.`

The test file contains a basic test designed to always pass. The absolute path of the file is `D:\Documents\CSCI_Project\test-app\test\testPractice.spec.ts`

**Steps Taken**

Based on the errors, it seems that the Karma cannot find my test files using the patterns given in  "files" part of the configuration file, karma.config.js. However, I have tried numerous patterns, including listing the exact relative path and ensuring that the path shown in the warning for that pattern is the absolute path of the file.

I think that typescript files are automatically converted to javascript files, but I tried using patterns ending in `.ts` instead of `.js`, which resulted in the karma warning `Unable to determine file type from the file extension, defaulting to js.`

At this point, I cannot think of what else the problem could have been. I am not very familiar with Karma, Jasmine, or Angular.

**Code/Pictures**

karma.conf.js file

```
// Generated on Sat Feb 06 2021 12:10:57 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      '*.js',
      'test/**/*.js',
      'test/*.js',
      'test/testPractice.js',
      'test/testPractice.spec.js',
    ],


    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Chrome window opened by Karma:
[picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZYv6.png)

Command line with Karma warnings:
[picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmUPL.png)

test file: testPractice.ts

```
describe("Practice Test", () =>{
    it("Should return true", ()=>{
        var test = true;
        expect(test).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The warnings about "does not match any file" makes sense, because the pattern `test/*.js` already matches the file `test/testPractice.js` and `test/testPractice.spec.js`, so the latter patterns are redundant.

I'm not sure why the test isn't actually running -- have you tried adding the `kjhtml` reporter (`npm install karma-jasmine-html-reporter`)?  I find it does a better job conveying exactly what tests ran along with individual status.